# Laravel4 ->whereIn: get all keywords per event

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, orm

I have the following query:

```
public function getEventsByKeywordIds($data){ 
    //Query events by dates 
    $query = DB::table('events')
                ->join('events_dates', function($join) use ($data){
                    $join->on('events.id', '=', 'events_dates.event_id')
                            ->where('events_dates.start_date', "<=", date_format(date_create($data['date_end']), "Y-m-d"))
                            ->where('events_dates.end_date', '>=', date_format(date_create($data['date_start']), "Y-m-d")); 
                }); 
    //Query events by keywords 
    $query = $query->join('events_keywords', function($join) use ($data){ 
                    $join->on('events.id', '=', 'events_keywords.event_id'); 
                })->whereIn('events_keywords.keyword_id', $data["keyword_ids"]); 

    //Query places 
    $query = $query->join('places', function($join) use ($data){ 
                    $join->on('events.place_id', '=', 'places.id'); 
                }); 
    //Set offset and limit 
    $query = $query
            ->take($data['limit'])
            ->offset($data['offset'])
            ->orderBy('events_dates.start_date', 'ASC')
            ->orderBy('events.name', 'ASC')
            ->groupBy('events.id'); 

   $events = $query->get(); 
   return $events; 
}
```

I am interested in the part that mentions "Query events by keywords".

`events_keywords`is a many-to-many table, linking event id's and keyword id's to each other.

The requirement exists to return **the keywords per event** to the client, but so far the query only returns 1 keyword per event that it returns.
Note: `$data["keyword_ids"]`is an array of keywords sent from the client, because only events related to certain keywords should be returned.

Do you have any suggestions to adapt this query in a simple way to meet the requirement?

Edit: what I require is actually the keyword names, which is stored in the keyword table (not the many-to-many.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by creating a many to many relationship through Laravel's `belongsToMany` relation.

```
    foreach($events as $event){ 
        $temp_event = EventModel::find($event->id); 
        $event->keywords = $temp_event->keywords; 
    } 

    return $events;
```

This is not the most efficient solution I'm sure, but it works.